# Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor is not defined when using DllPlugin and DllReferencePlugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am having the weirdest problem. I was trying to optimize my webpack bundle build time and followed a [tutorial](http://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/optimizing-webpack/) where the idea was to take out all vendor libraties, build them via seprate webpack config file using `webpack.DllPlugin` and `webpack.DllReferencePlugin` - that should allow me to rebuild only app code and do not rebuild vendors upon each small change in app code.

So I have created two config files.

**webpack.dll.config.js** for vendor files

```
var webpack   = require("webpack");
var path      = require("path");

module.exports = {
   entry: {
      vendor: ["./src/app/app_vendors.js"]
   },

   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build_dll", "js"),
      filename: "[name].js",
      sourceMapFilename: "[name].map",
      chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js",
      pathinfo: true
   },

   plugins: [
      new webpack.DllPlugin({
         path: path.join(__dirname, "build_dll", "[name]-manifest.json"),
         name: "[name]",
         context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "app")
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
   ],

   resolve: {
      modules: [
         path.resolve("./node_modules"),
         path.resolve("./src/app")
      ]
   }

}
```

**webpack.app.config.js** for app files

```
var webpack   = require("webpack");
var path      = require("path");

module.exports = {
   devtool: "source-map",
   cache:   true,

   entry: {
      app: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/app/app_client.js"]
   },

   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build_client", "js"),
      filename: "[name].js",
      sourceMapFilename: "[name].map",
      chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js",
      pathinfo: true
   },

   module: {
      rules: [{
         test: /\.jsx?/,
         include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/app"),
         exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
         loader: "babel-loader",
         options: {
            presets: [
               ["es2015", {"modules": false}], "stage-0", "react"
            ]
         },
      }]
   },

   resolve: {
      modules: [
         path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
         path.join(__dirname, "/src/app")
      ]
   },

   plugins: [
      new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
         context: path.join(__dirname, "src", "app"),
         manifest: require("./build_dll/vendor-manifest.json")
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
         name: "common", 
         filename: "common.js", 
         minChunks: 2, 
         chunks: ["app", "vendor"]
      })
   ]
};
```

This files do generate:

- `vendor.js` in `./build_dll/js`
- `vendor-manifest.json` in `./build_dll`
- `app.js` and `common.js` in `./build_client/js`

I then make sure to include `vendor.js`, `common.js` and `app.js` in my html (I also make sure that they are loaded from server via chrome dev console).

The problem is that when I rebuild everything without any errors and refresh my webpage I get this error:

```
external "vendor":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (external "vendor":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 590bc7b…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js from dll-reference vendor:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 590bc7b…:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:7134)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 590bc7b…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 590bc7b…:23)
    at app.js:1
```

And if I open my `app.js` file, I will have this as first lines and an error on the very first `module.exports`

```
webpackJsonp([0,1],[
/* 0 */
/* unknown exports provided */
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** external "vendor" ***!
  \*************************/
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = vendor; // ERROR HERE

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/* unknown exports provided */
/* all exports used */
/*!*****************************************************************************!*\
  !*** delegated ../../node_modules/react/react.js from dll-reference vendor ***!
  \*****************************************************************************/
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
...
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed a small part of the configuration. Inside the `output`, of you `webpack.dll.config.js`, you have to add the `library` option (*you can change it straight to **`vendor`** if you prefer)*

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build_client", "js"),
  filename: "[name].js",
  sourceMapFilename: "[name].map",
  pathinfo: true,
  library: '[name]_dll'
}
```

And after that you have to change the `DllPlugin` configuration accordingly

```
  new webpack.DllPlugin({
     path: path.join(__dirname, "build_dll", "[name]-manifest.json"),
     name: "[name]_dll",
     context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "app")
  })
```

This is because the DllPlugin expects to find the vendors inside a global scoped variable with e certain name (in your configuration, `vendor`) BUT you actually didn't exported it.

In order to do that, you just have to use the `library` option.